# How to parse the below JSON response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am getting the below JSON response after a ajax call.

```
{"head":{"json":"{ 'rows': [ {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'Gans Communications'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANNETTW'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANNONCO'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANSTIRE'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANTABSW'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANTONMI'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDALF'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDALF2'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDK'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDMTOW'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDOD'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDTOWI'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDY.LD'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANE .LD'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANICATL'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANKEMA'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANKEM4'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANLYWAL'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANN ETT'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANNETTT'} ]}"},"body":null,"responseTime":null,"leftPanel":null}
```

I have used tried to take CustName and CustId to display in textbox using Jquery.But i couldnot able to fetch the values properly.

Below is my sample code:

```
var results_customer=data.head.json;                    
var new_val = JSON.stringify(results_customer);                 
var newresult = eval(results_customer);
alert(newresult.length);
console.log(newresult);
```

I am getting error with above values.

Could any please help me in taking the values? Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no need to stringify. your result_customer should already contain the parsed data

Comment: You want **parse()** rather than **stringify()**. However, I am a little concerned about the single quotes for names like **{'rows': []}**.  JSON does not like single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bad encoded Json string in response. Json strings must be delimited by double quotes `"` and not with singles quotes `'`. So you have to convert it before using `JSON.parse()` method:

```js
var response = {"head":{"json":"{ 'rows': [ {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'Gans Communications'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANNETTW'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANNONCO'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANSTIRE'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANTABSW'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANTONMI'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDALF'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDALF2'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDK'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDMTOW'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDOD'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDTOWI'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANDY.LD'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANE .LD'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANICATL'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANKEMA'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANKEM4'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANLYWAL'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANN ETT'} , {'CustName' : 'JAMES', 'CustId' : 'GANNETTT'} ]}"},"body":null,"responseTime":null,"leftPanel":null};

var json = response.head.json.replace(/'/g, '"');

var data = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data);
```

Assuming your data does not contains singles quotes...

Comment: also i am having issue with replacing of ' to ''. If my response having values as xxx'x then this single quote also getting converted to double quotes. Is there any way to resolve this

Comment: If your values contains singles quotes _that are not escaped_, there is no way to fix it before the decoding, as php can't know wich quote has to be converted or not. So you have to fix it where the string is generated, in your back-end code, because the error is here, it generates bad json.